# Error reading resource.. access to path is denied(CS1566)

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.forms

I have created a binding library in iOS and when I try to rebuild the solution the build fails with the error message as " Error CS1566: Error reading resource 'SampleFramework' -- 'Access to the path '/Users/leonrodrigues/Projects/SampleFramework' is denied.' (CS1566) (SampleFramework.Binding).
anyone with any inputs on this as to how can we fix it ??

Comment: have you checked the file permissions on that folder?

Comment: Hi Jason Yes the file permissions are given to all the folders still this doesn't work for me.

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps and a basic  demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Hi Jessie I just followed exactly same steps mentioned in the microsoft link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/walkthrough

Here I get stuck at the second last step that is Building a binding library where while building the library project I get this error.

Comment: Please find my work under the github link below..Please download the .zip file and unzip it to use all the code that i have written for binding library. Kindly assist in this if anyone has any solution . Thanks

Github Link : https://github.com/LeoRods16/Xamarin_Widgets/tree/main

Comment: Hi , did you ever manage to run the official sample : https://github.com/xamcat/xamarin-binding-swift-framework ?

Comment: Hi @LeonCapg did you manage to find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add wrong path as native reference, may be parent folder. add the framework exact location